# Browserify: Exported function not found after bundling Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify

I'm using Browserify to create a bundle which contains an exported function that I want to call within a `<script>` tag. Everything works fine until I `require` Bootstrap, at which point the function is no longer accessible and I get the error:

> TypeError: mainBundle.greeting is not a function

Here's the code:

JavaScript (*main.js*):

```
window.jQuery = require('jquery');
window.$ = global.jQuery;

module.exports = {
  greeting
};

function greeting (name) {
  return `Hello ${name}!`;
}
```

HTML

```
<script src="js/bundle.js"></script>
<script>
  // Update greeting
  $('#greeting').text(mainBundle.greeting('Foo'));
</script>
```

Gulpfile:

Taken pretty much from the [Gulp Browserify recipe](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/fast-browserify-builds-with-watchify.md). You can see I've added the `standalone` option to `customOpts` to generate a standalone module as well as `require`  to add Bootstrap. The issue occurs when the `require` line is commented in.

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
const watchify = require('watchify');
const browserify = require('browserify');
const source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
const buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');
const log = require('gulplog');

// add custom browserify options here
const customOpts = {
  entries: ['./src/js/main.js'],
  // require: ['bootstrap', 'jquery'],  // UNCOMMENT CAUSES ISSUE
  standalone: 'mainBundle',
  debug: true
};
const opts = {...watchify.args, ...customOpts};
const b = watchify(browserify(opts));
console.log('Browserify options: ', opts);

// add transformations here
// i.e. b.transform(coffeeify);

exports.js = bundle; // so you can run `gulp js` to build the file
b.on('update', bundle); // on any dep update, runs the bundler
b.on('log', log.info); // output build logs to terminal

function bundle() {
  return b.bundle()
  // log errors if they happen
    .on('error', log.error.bind(log, 'Browserify Error'))
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    // optional, remove if you don't need to buffer file contents
    .pipe(buffer())
    // optional, remove if you dont want sourcemaps
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true})) // loads map from browserify file
    // Add transformation tasks to the pipeline here.
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./')) // writes .map file
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, putting the `require` in *main.js* resolves the issue:

```
const bootstrap = require('bootstrap');
window.jQuery = require('jquery');
window.$ = global.jQuery;

module.exports = {
  greeting
};

function greeting (name) {
  return `Hello ${name}!`;
}
```

If anyone has a better answer that would allow me to use the Browserify `require` option, I will happily accept your answer. I would prefer to use the config option to avoid importing things that are not explicitly required in my scripts.